# Setting different color on some grid items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to set different grid item background color based on weather the model for that item has some boolean set to tru or false. So in my `onBindViewHolder` method in my `MyRecyclerviewAdapter` I check:

```
if (current.hasWiki()) {
        holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
    }
```

When the recycler grid view is loaded, it looks fine, item that have that hasWiki==true are colored green, and that hasWiki==false are not colored at all. But when I scroll down and those uncolored items are not showing on the screen anymore, I scroll up again and these items that are supposed to be uncolored, are colored green now. It is all messed up.

This is my MyViewHolder:

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
}
```

So, how can I fix these undesirable behavior? Is there another way to set different color to recyclerview items based on some arbitrary flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

> ```
> if (current.hasWiki()) {
>     holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
> }
> ```

to this:

```
if (current.hasWiki()) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
} else {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(/* default color here */);
}
```

When you're dealing with `RecyclerView`, it's important to understand that your `ViewHolder`s will be *recycled* and *reused*. So if you ever want something to happen "sometimes," you need to make sure that you always set the state back to the default when "sometimes" isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of recycling views or even when you use the old approach with normal list views. The problem you're facing is that you're not actually recycling the view. The recycler view will pass in view holders that contain old views that need to be recycled. In other words, as you scroll you'll be receiving views that were previously set to green and that now need to be set to white (or whatever colour you'd want). Remember that there's no guarantee that if you previously received a view holder for view `xyz` the next time you scroll to that view you'll receive the same holder. It can be a different one.

The bit of logic that you show:

```
if (current.hasWiki()) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
}
```

is correct, but what about item's you're recycling and they should have a white background (or any other colour for that matter)? These are not set, but they have to be.

```
if (current.hasWiki()) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
} else {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

This way you ensure that the background for each view is correctly recycled. Now, what is said here for the background holds true for any view in the view holder, including images - They have to be correctly set a.k.a. recycled - this is why it's called a recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an `else` statement in your onBindViewHolder() method

```
if (current.hasWiki()) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCCF0FCC0);
} else{
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```